# Rescheduling a Job for a day and then again same should start

Tags: linux

I want to reschedule job for just a day.
my existing job is

```
30 03 * * * /home/xyz/delete_full.sh
```

I want it to run it at

```
00 04 27 * * /home/xyz/delete_full.sh
```

and again the job should run as it is from the next day.

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far. Also what do you want to use to achieve that: systemd.timer or cron?

Comment: You should look at `at` to run one off jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
30 03 1-26,28-31 * * /home/xyz/delete_full.sh
00 04 27 * * /home/xyz/delete_full.sh
```

i.e. schedule `/home/xyz/delete_full.sh` to run every day at 03:20 **but** the 27th of every month and run at 04:00 **on** the 27th of the month.